# Настройка роутинга в Yii2

Tags: yii2, роутинг

Я использую шаблон advanced в Yii2. Frontend сделал, там все хорошо работает, но когда начал делать backend - наткнулся на ошибку.

Я делаю через красивые урлы, то есть пишу

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '/' => 'admin/index',
            '/add' => 'admin/add-page',
        ],
    ]
```

То есть, по идее по адресу ***http://mysite.ru/add-page*** у меня должен вызваться метод ***actionAddPage()*** контроллера ***AdminController***. Но мне выдает просто

```
Not Found

The requested URL /add was not found on this server.
```

При чем, что в frontend все прекрасно работает. Помогите понять в чем проблема

Comment: по-моему вы запутались, при переходе на url `/add` у вас будет вызываться роут 'admin/add-page'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема заключалась в том, что не было файла ***.htaccess***